# python list of lists takes 10 times more memory than expected

Tags: python

The python list of list is super inefficient. Even in simplest case it takes about 10 times more memory than simple list with the very same data. The following code illustrated the problem:

```
import memory_profiler
import sys

t=[]

m=memory_profiler.memory_usage()
t= ["one two three four five" for l in range(60000000)]
print ("getsize={} | memory_usage={}".format(sys.getsizeof(t),memory_profiler.memory_usage()[0]-m[0]))


m=memory_profiler.memory_usage()
t= [["one two three four five"] for l in range(60000000)]
print ("getsize={} | memory_usage={}".format(sys.getsizeof(t),memory_profiler.memory_usage()[0]-m[0]))

import gc
gc.collect()
print ("getsize={} | memory_usage={}".format(sys.getsizeof(t),memory_profiler.memory_usage()[0]-m[0]))
```

This code outputs something like:

```
getsize=536721616 | memory_usage=459.4375
getsize=536721616 | memory_usage=4181.0703125
getsize=536721616 | memory_usage=4181.0703125
```

Is there any way to cure this behavior?

Using generator is not an option, I need the data in memory for later processing by multiple workers. The data has to be in list of lists format.

Comment: Any list of lists equivalent that is memory efficient (as opposed to CPU efficient) would work for me. The question is if there is such a thing?

Comment: Your measurements are misleading. Each version of `t` here uses only one `"one two three four five"` string object; the string's size has essentially no effect on your measurements.

Comment: Also, `t` is clearly still reachable when you call `gc.collect()`.

Comment: `sys.getsizeof(t)` only counted the list it self, as a container, basically it is 60000000 pointers with some overhead, you need add up size of strings, then overall memory_usage number will match

Comment: Without more information of your requirements, write to disk, consider buffering or refactor your pipeline to work with generators.

Answer (score 2):

Lists in python are resizeable arrays. To give you an efficient implementation of `list.append()`, some memory is preallocated after the list's actual storage.

Tuple do not have this issue, they are immutable hence the memory allocation can fit the actually used size. Try changing `["one two three four five"]` to `("one two three four five",)` (don't forget the `,` as I did in my original message, otherwise it's not a tuple): the memory usage drops considerably. I get (for 600000 to avoid blowing off the RAM of my laptop):

```
getsize=4826320 | memory_usage=18.94140625
getsize=4826320 | memory_usage=4.2421875
getsize=4826320 | memory_usage=4.2421875
```

It's actually surprising that it drops below the plain list implementation, but I don't have an explanation for that!

Anyway, if you're starting to worry about performance, it most likely mean that Python, or at least Python's native data-structure are not the right tool. For example, if you want to manipulate matrices, lists of lists of numbers will be a real pain while NumPy's array will be both efficient and convenient.

Comment: `("one two three four five")` is not a tuple; it's just `"one two three four five"` in grouping parentheses. `("one two three four five",)` is a length-1 tuple.

Comment: Oups, indeed. Good catch!

Comment: ... but surprisingly, adding the comma reduces the memory usage even a bit more.

Comment: Like with the plain string, Python isn't actually building 60 million separate tuples; the peephole optimizer has precomputed the tuple, and a single tuple object is being used for all list entries. Also, be aware that the code in the question is printing differences in memory usage, not actual memory usage; for example, a small but positive value for the second `memory_usage` print indicates a small increase in the process's memory consumption. (It doesn't reset `m` after the second print, so the third print doesn't mean memory usage increased again.)

Comment: If you want to see what the memory usage looks like with 60 million tuples, you can save the string to a variable and build tuples using the variable: `x = 'one two...'` and then `(x,)` to build the tuple. The optimizer can't currently optimize that.